# Incorrect mapping of project root in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have this method for parsing a `json` file:

```
private static HealthRegex GetHealthRegex()
{
    // read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
    HealthRegex healthRegex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HealthRegex>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Path\\To\\My\\App\\src\\my.app\\Config\\config.json"));
    return healthRegex;
}
```

Instead of hard coding the entire path I'd like to reference the file location from the project root. I thought it should have been this:

```
File.ReadAllText(@"~\\Config\\config.json")
```

When I try to run that I get this exception:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Path\To\My\\App\src\my.app\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\~\src\my.app\Config\config.json'.
```

What is the correct way to reference this?

Comment: Why would you expect that a tilde would work?

Comment: The file should be in the bin\ file. For that in the solution explorer click the file, open the property explorer. chosse copy in different or always copy. Then you parth should be relative to the exe. there should be a good dupe with picture out there, but can't find it for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to have `~` symbol. Just use `File.ReadAllText(@"Config\\config.json")`.
But note, that during execution, root path will be `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` folder - so make sure that your json file is placed to that location.

I also set the following on my `config.json`:

[image: I set the following:]